# How to tell qmake to use .dll.a suffix for shared libraries

Tags: qt, mingw, qmake

When building Qt projects (e.g. Qwt) with qmake on Windows using MinGW-w64 I notice shared libraries get the `.a` suffix instead of `.dll.a`.

Since I want to build both static and shared libraries the static and shared library have the same name ending in `.a`.

How can I tell qmake to use the `.dll.a` extension for shared libraries?

P.S.: In case you are wondering how to build static libraries with qmake: just add `CONFIG+=staticlib` to the `qmake` command.

Answer (score 2):

When you build shared library with `CONFIG += sharedlib` , you get the DLL file along with `.a` file as wrapper for DLL, it only contains instructions how get symbols from DLL; this `.a` file is statically build so you can choose its extension with `QMAKE_EXTENSION_STATICLIB`  .. this is how it looks in .pro

```
TEMPLATE = lib
CONFIG += sharedlib
CONFIG(sharedlib, staticlib|sharedlib): { QMAKE_EXTENSION_STATICLIB = dll.a }
```

This should generate what you want, along withe DLL!

Needless to say, when you switch to static compile `CONFIG += staticlib` .. you just get the `.a` library file

.. yes its a bit confusing! and funny .. if you want to simplify , then you might want to think of changing your strategy .. for example instead of having `.dll.a` extension for dynamic library .. you could just change the extension of the static lib!

```
TEMPLATE = lib
CONFIG += staticlib
CONFIG(staticlib, staticlib|sharedlib): { QMAKE_EXTENSION_STATICLIB = static.a }
```

Thus you get `.a` for the shared library , and `.static.a` for the static library ..

Comment: Thanks for the explication. Very confusing I must say. Why is the `.a` file for the shared library statically built? To be honest I was looking for a simple solution to add something to the `qmake` command line. However adding `QMAKE_EXTENSION_STATICLIB=dll.a` to the `qmake` command for Qwt results in `make[2]: *** No rule to make target 'D:/Prog/winlibs64-9.2.0/custombuilt/qt/lib/libQt5PrintSupport.dll.a', needed by '../lib/qwt.dll'.  Stop.`, same when editing the `.pri` file following your suggestions. So it seems it may need to be set in more than one place...

Comment: @BrechtSanders, Yes can be used from command line. this is very simple .. it just outputs the name as needed.what I see from the error you show, is that the naming goes correct `dll.a` .. and that was your question. Now why Qwt is not accepting that name is something to be investigated around Qwt ..

Comment: Don't you mean `QMAKE_EXTENSION_SHLIB=.dll.a` ?